# C - Copying Array of Strings into a Struct

Tags: c, pointers

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for a couple hours now.

I have a struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct historyNode {
    int pos;
    char cmd[MAXLINE];
    char* args[(MAXLINE / 2) + 1];
    struct historyNode* next;
} historyNode_t;
```

I am attempting to copy a passed-in array of strings into the `args` field within the above struct. This happens in the method below:

```
void addToHistory(history_t* history, char* args[(MAXLINE / 2) + 1]) {
    historyNode_t* node = malloc(sizeof(historyNode_t));

    ...

    int index = 0;
    while (args[index] != NULL) {
        node->args[index] = args[index];

    ...
```

When I attempt to access this node's `args` value at a later time outside of the method, it spits out a value equal to whatever is in the passed-in `args` array at that moment; ie, the values aren't actually being copied, but rather the addresses are.

I feel like this is simple but it is frustrating me. Any tips on how this can be remedied are super appreciated.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The only thing that the structure contains are pointers, so any time you look at them, you'll always see whatever is being pointed to, by those pointers, at the given time. Remember: a computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do. You wanted your computer to have pointers in this structure, and you've set them accordingly, so whatever those pointers are pointing to is what you'll see when you will use those pointers at any point later. That's what a pointer is, by definition.

Comment: To add to what @SamVarshavchik has said, you may want to allocate some memory within the `addToHistory()` function that can be used to store copies of the strings pointed to by the passed `args[]` pointers. Those copies can be referenced by the `args[]` pointers within the new `struct`.

Comment: You have run into the difference between shallow and deep copies. This is a fundamental concept, and if you strip away all of the superfluous complication in this example, the problem -- and solution -- should become clear to you. (This is one of the reasons we ask for [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); they don't just make our job easier, they make the whole thing clearer to *you.)*

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback! Sorry if my question was not clear, but what Sam and David said was super helpful. The idea of allocating memory for the strings was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I attempt to access this node's args value at a later time outside of the method

For doing that you should've returned pointer to `struct historyNode` wherever you are trying to access the `args` value. Here is an example for that:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 struct node
 {
     char *a[2];
 };

 struct node *fun()
 {
     char *c[]={"hello","World"};
     struct node *ptr= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     ptr->a[0]=c[0];
     ptr->a[1]=c[1];
     return ptr;
 }

 int main()
 {
     struct node *ptr=fun();
     printf("%s %s\n",ptr->a[0],ptr->a[1]);
     return 0;
 }
```

**OUTPUT:** `hello World`

Comment: It should be `char *a[2]`in your case as you have 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

In C, C++,

```
char   charA[10];        // Array of char (i.e., string) up to 9+1 byte
                         // 10 bytes of memory is reserved

char  *string;           // Pointer to a null-terminated string
                         // Memory for 1 pointer (4 or 8 bytes) are reserved
                         // Need to allocate arbitrary bytes of memory
                         // Up to programmer to interpret the memory structure
                         // E.g.,
                         //   As array of pointers to string
                         //   A long string 
                         //   etc.
                         // This pointer could be passed to other functions
                         // and content at that pointed address could be changed

//char  *strings[];      // Cannot declare pointer to unknown length of array
                         // Use char** as below

char **ptrs2Strings;     // Pointer to pointer to char
                         // Memory for 1 pointer (4 or 8 bytes) are reserved
                         // Need to allocate arbitrary bytes of memory 
                         // Up to programmer to interpret the memory structure
                         // E.g.,
                         //   As array of pointers to string
                         //   A long string 
                         //   etc.
                         // The pointer to pointer could be passed to other 
                         // functions. The content at that pointed address is
                         // only an address to an user-allocated memory.
                         // These functions could change this second address as
                         // well as content of the memory pointed by the second
                         // address.

char  *charvar[10];      // array of 10 char pointers
                         // Memory for 10 pointers (40 or 80 bytes) are reserved
                         // Programmer could  allocate arbitrary bytes of memory 
                         // for each char pointer

char   stringA[10][256]; // array of 10 strings, and each string could store 
                         //   up to 255+1 bytes
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: `char *strings[]` is an incomplete array of pointers to `char`, not a "pointer to unknown length of array" (which would be `char (*strings)[]`). It isn't at all clear to me how this answers the OP's question, though.